# Swift: Asynchronous dataTask never terminates

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, nsurlsession

I have a function that scrapes a JSON file embedded in a website and returns a string array. Since the data it returns is essential for my view controller, I need this function to run before the view loads. It is called in the view controller's initialization.

```
func scrapeBuses() -> [String] {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    //config.waitsForConnectivity = true
    let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let url = URL(string: link to a JSON file)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    var loops = [String]()
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            do {
                print("Getting information from website")
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 {
                    print("in async")
                    loops.append("test2")
                }
            }
            catch { print(error)}
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    print("about to return")
    //return loops
    }
    group.wait()
    return loops
}
```

Since it is asynchronous, I added the `DispatchGroup` and the `wait()` statements so that my main thread waits until this essential data has been scraped before continuing with the rest of the thread. However, I have noticed that when the segue to this view controller occurs (ie, when the view controller is initialized) nothing else is printed and the simulation stops. Clearly this means that the main thread is waiting for `scrape()` to finish, but why does it run infinitely? When I access the website, both in my web browser and in Rested, I can see that it correctly hosts the JSON.

Edit:

I tried another version of the same function using a completion handler instead of `DispatchQueue.wait()`. Below is the code:

```
func scrapeBuses(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.cmunc.net/assets/appData.json")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    var loops = [String]()

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            print("Getting information from website")
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 {
                print("in async")
                loops.append("test2")
            }
            completion(loops)
        }
        task.resume()
}
```

And here is the function which is called by the view controller's `init`:

```
func refresh() {
    var newArray = [String]()
    scrapeBuses { loops in
        newArray = loops
        print("calling scrapeBuses closure")
    }
    print(newArray)
}
```

Using the completion handler, the code executes correctly. Both the print statements in `scrapeBuses` and those in the closeure print. Huge thanks to everyone who offered their insight.

Comment: Don't misuse `DispatchGroup` to make an asynchronous task synchronous. **Never do that**. Use a completion handler. And don't use `NSMutable...` classes if there is a native Swift counterpart.

Comment: I tried with a completion handler, nothing changed.

On a side note, why is making an asynchronous task synchronous problematic?

Comment: Because the current thread is blocked. `DispatchGroup` is useful to get ***notified*** in a loop when all tasks are completed but not for a single task.

Comment: _I tried with a completion handler, nothing changed._ Please show what you tried in your question. Very likely you are misusing completion handler. Anyway **NEVER** wait in the main thread.

Comment: Please post valid code. You have mismatched curly braces. The `do/catch` is unnecessary since nothing inside the `do` block throws.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for pointing that out, the code has been updated

Comment: @OOPer I have edited the question to include the updated version with the completion handler.

Comment: Please try to understand how asynchronous data processing works. You have to put `print(newArray)` (or the real code to process the array) **into** the closure because the closure is executed much **later**  after `refresh` has finished.

Comment: `task.resume()` is missing. How can the task call a closure if the task isn‘t started?

Comment: My point is that no code inside the closure is executed at all. The `print("calling scrapeBuses closure")` is inside the closure and is not executed.

Comment: As I guessed, you are misusing completion handler pattern. I guess you know you usually setup view in the `viewDidLoad()` method. Because iOS calls the method when all the views are ready for setup. As well. You need to write all things you use your `loops` inside the completion handler. Because your updated code calls the method when your `loops` is ready to use.

Comment: And you need to remove `DispatchQueue.main.async {` `}` from your completion handler code.

Comment: And one more, your updated code is missing `task.resume()`.

Comment: With including the exact code of your second update, I get **Getting information from website** / **in async** / **calling scrapeBuses closure**. You may be testing a different code than you have shown. And as already noted by vadian, `print(newArray)` needs to be inside the completion handler.

Comment: @OOPer you are correct; the currenlty updated code works well. I have one final question that might be off topic: the `loops` array is needed in the `TableView Cells` of a `TableView`, which is the view controller where these functions are being run. Since `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` is called by (I assume) `viewDidLoad`, which is in turn called by `init`, how do you recommend that I ensure the `TableView Controller` has the value it needs before `cellForRowAt` is called?

Comment: Make your dataSource empty until your `loops` is ready. When it is ready, you fill the dataSource and call `reloadData().

Comment: That works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a completion handler to your `scrapeBuses` func.

```
func scrapeBuses(completion: ([String]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    // etc (remove all mentions of groups)

    let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        do {
            print("Getting information from website")
            if let error = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { // Call back on the main queue
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            } else if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 {
                print("in async")
                loops.append("test2")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(loops, nil)
            }
        } 
        catch { 
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

then…

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 

    scrapeBuses { loops, error in
        if let error = error {    
            print(error)
            return
        }
        // Do something with loops
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a version with this completion handler style to the question; using your method, the main queue is no longer halted, but no code in the function closure nor in the dataTask block are executed.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Adding breakpoints and stepping through the code?

Answer (score 0):

Because you missed

```
loops.append("test2")
group.leave()
```

Or better in top of callback

```
defer { group.leave() }
```

BTW , it's better to have an activity indicator , instead of `wait`

//

Try this

```
func scrapeBuses(completion:@escaping(_ res:[String]?) -> Void ) {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    //config.waitsForConnectivity = true
    let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let url = URL(string: link to a JSON file)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    var loops = [String]()
    let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            do {
                print("Getting information from website")
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                     completion(nil)
                } else if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 {
                    print("in async")
                    loops.append("test2")
                    completion(loops)
                }
            }
            catch { print(error)
                     completion(nil)
                  }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: Adding `group.leave()` after the append statement didn't change anything. Where would the `defer` statement go? After the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block?

Comment: BTW you should use group for many asynchronous tasks that you want when they all end

Comment: @Sh_Khan The very first part of your answer is incorrect. The call the `leave` (if used) needs to be called at the end of the completion block no matter if there is an error or not.

Comment: and that's why i said **defer** as better to be called in any case